# Implementing second controller in ServiceNow Service Portal

Tags: angularjs, servicenow

I would like to implement Table pagination in ServiceNow Service Portal. I couldn't figure out a way to implement second controller from Client Script. It throws error "**Uncaught Error: Unknown provider: $compileProvider from ngAria**". Here is Client Script and HTMl of Widget

[Click here to see Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZjwn.png)

HTML:

```
    <html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/css/bootstrap.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/2.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.0/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sortingOrder = 'name';
</script>

<div ng-controller="ctrlRead">
    <div class="input-append">
        <input type="text" ng-model="query" ng-change="search()" class="input-large search-query" placeholder="Search">
        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-search"></i></span>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="id">Id&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('id')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a></th>
            <th class="name">Name&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('name')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a></th>
            <th class="description">Description&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('description')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a></th>
            <th class="field3">Field 3&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('field3')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a></th>
            <th class="field4">Field 4&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('field4')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a></th>
            <th class="field5">Field 5&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('field5')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
        <td colspan="6">
            <div class="pagination pull-right">
                <ul>
                    <li ng-class="{disabled: currentPage == 0}">
                        <a href ng-click="prevPage()">« Prev</a>
                    </li>
                    <li ng-repeat="n in range(pagedItems.length)"
                        ng-class="{active: n == currentPage}"
                        ng-click="setPage()">
                        <a href ng-bind="n + 1">1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li ng-class="{disabled: currentPage == pagedItems.length - 1}">
                        <a href ng-click="nextPage()">Next »</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in pagedItems[currentPage] | orderBy:sortingOrder:reverse">
            <td>{{item.id}}</td>
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            <td>{{item.description}}</td>
            <td>{{item.field3}}</td>
            <td>{{item.field4}}</td>
            <td>{{item.field5}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>


</html>
```

Client Script:

```
function($scope,$filter)
{
    var c=this;
    c.getData = function() 
    {

        c.server.get().then(
            function(response)
            {  
                //c.data.tableData=response.data.tableData;
                //jsonTable=response.data.tableData;
                c.data.tableData= angular.fromJson(response.data.tableData);
            })
    };
c.getData();
```

}

```
ctrlRead.$inject('$scope', '$filter',c.data.tableData);
    // init
function ctrlRead($scope, $filter,c.data.tableData)
{
            $scope.sortingOrder = sortingOrder;
            $scope.reverse = false;
            $scope.filteredItems = [];
            $scope.groupedItems = [];
            $scope.itemsPerPage = 5;
            $scope.pagedItems = [];
            $scope.currentPage = 0;
            $scope.items = [
                {"id":"1","name":"name 1","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 1","field4":"field4 1","field5 ":"field5 1"},
                {"id":"2","name":"name 2","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 2","field4":"field4 2","field5 ":"field5 2"},
                {"id":"3","name":"name 3","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 3","field4":"field4 3","field5 ":"field5 3"},
                {"id":"4","name":"name 4","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 4","field4":"field4 4","field5 ":"field5 4"},
                {"id":"5","name":"name 5","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 5","field4":"field4 5","field5 ":"field5 5"},
                {"id":"6","name":"name 6","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 6","field4":"field4 6","field5 ":"field5 6"},
                {"id":"7","name":"name 7","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 7","field4":"field4 7","field5 ":"field5 7"},
                {"id":"8","name":"name 8","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 8","field4":"field4 8","field5 ":"field5 8"},
                {"id":"9","name":"name 9","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 9","field4":"field4 9","field5 ":"field5 9"},
                {"id":"10","name":"name 10","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 10","field4":"field4 10","field5 ":"field5 10"},
                {"id":"11","name":"name 11","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 11","field4":"field4 11","field5 ":"field5 11"},
                {"id":"12","name":"name 12","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 12","field4":"field4 12","field5 ":"field5 12"},
                {"id":"13","name":"name 13","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 13","field4":"field4 13","field5 ":"field5 13"},
                {"id":"14","name":"name 14","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 14","field4":"field4 14","field5 ":"field5 14"},
                {"id":"15","name":"name 15","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 15","field4":"field4 15","field5 ":"field5 15"},
                {"id":"16","name":"name 16","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 16","field4":"field4 16","field5 ":"field5 16"},
                {"id":"17","name":"name 17","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 17","field4":"field4 17","field5 ":"field5 17"},
                {"id":"18","name":"name 18","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 18","field4":"field4 18","field5 ":"field5 18"},
                {"id":"19","name":"name 19","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 19","field4":"field4 19","field5 ":"field5 19"},
                {"id":"20","name":"name 20","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 20","field4":"field4 20","field5 ":"field5 20"}
            ];

            //$scope.items =JSON.parse(data);
            //$scope.items=getData2();
            var searchMatch = function (haystack, needle) {
                if (!needle) {
                    return true;
                }
                return haystack.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
            };

            // init the filtered items
            $scope.search = function () {
                $scope.filteredItems = $filter('filter')($scope.items, function (item) {
                    for(var attr in item) {
                        if (searchMatch(item[attr], $scope.query))
                            return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                });
                // take care of the sorting order
                if ($scope.sortingOrder !== '') {
                    $scope.filteredItems = $filter('orderBy')($scope.filteredItems, $scope.sortingOrder, $scope.reverse);
                }
                $scope.currentPage = 0;
                // now group by pages
                $scope.groupToPages();
            };

            // calculate page in place
            $scope.groupToPages = function () {
                $scope.pagedItems = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.filteredItems.length; i++) {
                    if (i % $scope.itemsPerPage === 0) {
                        $scope.pagedItems[Math.floor(i / $scope.itemsPerPage)] = [ $scope.filteredItems[i] ];
                    } else {
                        $scope.pagedItems[Math.floor(i / $scope.itemsPerPage)].push($scope.filteredItems[i]);
                    }
                }
            };

            $scope.range = function (start, end) {
                var ret = [];
                if (!end) {
                    end = start;
                    start = 0;
                }
                for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
                    ret.push(i);
                }
                return ret;
            };

            $scope.prevPage = function () {
                if ($scope.currentPage > 0) {
                    $scope.currentPage--;
                }
            };

            $scope.nextPage = function () {
                if ($scope.currentPage < $scope.pagedItems.length - 1) {
                    $scope.currentPage++;
                }
            };

            $scope.setPage = function () {
                $scope.currentPage = this.n;
            };

            // functions have been describe process the data for display
            $scope.search();

            // change sorting order
            $scope.sort_by = function(newSortingOrder) {
                if ($scope.sortingOrder == newSortingOrder)
                    $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;

                $scope.sortingOrder = newSortingOrder;

                // icon setup
                $('th i').each(function(){
                    // icon reset
                    $(this).removeClass().addClass('icon-sort');
                });
                if ($scope.reverse)
                    $('th.'+new_sorting_order+' i').removeClass().addClass('icon-chevron-up');
                else
                    $('th.'+new_sorting_order+' i').removeClass().addClass('icon-chevron-down');
            };
        }




    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issue few months back. The way angular works (the way you write) in Servicenow is kind of different.  I made few changes to your script, can you try this.

```
function($scope,$filter)
{
var c=this;
c.getData = function() 
{

    c.server.get().then(
        function(response)
        {  
            //c.data.tableData=response.data.tableData;
            //jsonTable=response.data.tableData;
            c.data.tableData= angular.fromJson(response.data.tableData);
        })
};


c.ctrlRead =function(data) 
{

    $scope.sortingOrder = sortingOrder;
    $scope.reverse = false;
    $scope.filteredItems = [];
    $scope.groupedItems = [];
    $scope.itemsPerPage = 5;
    $scope.pagedItems = [];
    $scope.currentPage = 0;
    $scope.items = [
        {"id":"1","name":"name 1","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 1","field4":"field4 1","field5 ":"field5 1"},
        {"id":"2","name":"name 2","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 2","field4":"field4 2","field5 ":"field5 2"},
        {"id":"3","name":"name 3","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 3","field4":"field4 3","field5 ":"field5 3"},
        {"id":"4","name":"name 4","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 4","field4":"field4 4","field5 ":"field5 4"},
        {"id":"5","name":"name 5","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 5","field4":"field4 5","field5 ":"field5 5"},
        {"id":"6","name":"name 6","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 6","field4":"field4 6","field5 ":"field5 6"},
        {"id":"7","name":"name 7","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 7","field4":"field4 7","field5 ":"field5 7"},
        {"id":"8","name":"name 8","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 8","field4":"field4 8","field5 ":"field5 8"},
        {"id":"9","name":"name 9","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 9","field4":"field4 9","field5 ":"field5 9"},
        {"id":"10","name":"name 10","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 10","field4":"field4 10","field5 ":"field5 10"},
        {"id":"11","name":"name 11","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 11","field4":"field4 11","field5 ":"field5 11"},
        {"id":"12","name":"name 12","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 12","field4":"field4 12","field5 ":"field5 12"},
        {"id":"13","name":"name 13","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 13","field4":"field4 13","field5 ":"field5 13"},
        {"id":"14","name":"name 14","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 14","field4":"field4 14","field5 ":"field5 14"},
        {"id":"15","name":"name 15","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 15","field4":"field4 15","field5 ":"field5 15"},
        {"id":"16","name":"name 16","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 16","field4":"field4 16","field5 ":"field5 16"},
        {"id":"17","name":"name 17","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 17","field4":"field4 17","field5 ":"field5 17"},
        {"id":"18","name":"name 18","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 18","field4":"field4 18","field5 ":"field5 18"},
        {"id":"19","name":"name 19","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 19","field4":"field4 19","field5 ":"field5 19"},
        {"id":"20","name":"name 20","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 20","field4":"field4 20","field5 ":"field5 20"}
    ];

    //$scope.items =JSON.parse(data);
    //$scope.items=getData2();
    var searchMatch = function (haystack, needle) {
        if (!needle) {
            return true;
        }
        return haystack.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    };

    // init the filtered items
    $scope.search = function () {
        $scope.filteredItems = $filter('filter')($scope.items, function (item) {
            for(var attr in item) {
                if (searchMatch(item[attr], $scope.query))
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
        // take care of the sorting order
        if ($scope.sortingOrder !== '') {
            $scope.filteredItems = $filter('orderBy')($scope.filteredItems, $scope.sortingOrder, $scope.reverse);
        }
        $scope.currentPage = 0;
        // now group by pages
        $scope.groupToPages();
    };

    // calculate page in place
    $scope.groupToPages = function () {
        $scope.pagedItems = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.filteredItems.length; i++) {
            if (i % $scope.itemsPerPage === 0) {
                $scope.pagedItems[Math.floor(i / $scope.itemsPerPage)] = [ $scope.filteredItems[i] ];
            } else {
                $scope.pagedItems[Math.floor(i / $scope.itemsPerPage)].push($scope.filteredItems[i]);
            }
        }
    };

    $scope.range = function (start, end) {
        var ret = [];
        if (!end) {
            end = start;
            start = 0;
        }
        for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
            ret.push(i);
        }
        return ret;
    };

    $scope.prevPage = function () {
        if ($scope.currentPage > 0) {
            $scope.currentPage--;
        }
    };

    $scope.nextPage = function () {
        if ($scope.currentPage < $scope.pagedItems.length - 1) {
            $scope.currentPage++;
        }
    };

    $scope.setPage = function () {
        $scope.currentPage = this.n;
    };

    // functions have been describe process the data for display
    $scope.search();

    // change sorting order
    $scope.sort_by = function(newSortingOrder) {
        if ($scope.sortingOrder == newSortingOrder)
            $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;

        $scope.sortingOrder = newSortingOrder;

        // icon setup
        $('th i').each(function(){
            // icon reset
            $(this).removeClass().addClass('icon-sort');
        });
        if ($scope.reverse)
            $('th.'+new_sorting_order+' i').removeClass().addClass('icon-chevron-up');
        else
            $('th.'+new_sorting_order+' i').removeClass().addClass('icon-chevron-down');
    };
}

c.getData();
c.ctrlRead(c.data.tableData);
}
```

Comment: Let me try. Can you explain this?

Comment: Sure. If you got to the console, you can see following code


api.controller=function()
{
 var c=this;
 c.getData = function() 
 {
             //your code
 };
 c.getData();

}

ServiceNow converts widget client script as controller. 'c' is nothing but 'this'. The only way you can inject dependencies is mentioned in my answer.


I would refer you to https://github.com/service-portal/documentation/blob/master/documentation/widget_client_script.md  for more info.